# Holographic self-energy for a scalar field in a slice of AdS

Tags: quantum-field-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, ads-cft, holographic-principle, self-energy

I am confused about a key step in Gherghetta's "[TASI Lectures on a Holographic View of Beyond the Standard Model Physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2570)" in the derivation of the holographic self-energy in the strongly coupled dual to a 5D scalar field in a slice of AdS.

The metric is:
$$ds^2=  e^{-2ky}\eta_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + dy^2$$ with $\eta = \text{diag}(-+++)$.

### 1. Bulk scalar solution

We start with equation (93), which is the solution to the bulk equation of motion in momentum space for the Minkowski directions and position space in the extra dimension:

$$\Phi(p,z) = \Phi(p) A^{-2}(z)\left[ J_\alpha(iq) - \frac{J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_1)}{Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_1)}Y_\alpha (iq) \right].$$

Here we go to the $z$ coordinates for the extra dimension defined by:

$$z = \frac{e^{ky}-1}{k}
\quad\quad
A(z) = \frac{1}{1+kz}
\quad\quad
q = \frac{p}{k\,A(z)}.
$$

I believe this is to be compared to the modes of a KK decomposition, written in a general form in equation (68), but explicitly for a scalar field as equation (20):

$$f^{(n)}_\Phi (y)=
N_\Phi^{(n)} e^{2ky}
\left[
J_\alpha\left(\frac{m_n}{ke^{-ky}}\right)
+ b_\Phi^{(n)} Y_\alpha \left(\frac{m_n}{ke^{-ky}}\right)
\right].
$$

**Question 1**: I can see how these two equations have the same functional form with $m_n\to p$. However, I do not quite understand how we fixed $b_\Phi^{(n)}$ to be $-J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_1)/Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_1)$ and am not even totally sure what $q_1$ means. Is this $p/k\, A(z_\text{IR})$, that is $q$ evaluated at the IR boundary? Presumably this is to impose Neumann boundary conditions, but it is not obvious why that is significant here.

**Question 2**: why is it significant to factorize $\Phi(p,z)$ into three factors?

1. A piece that depends on the momentum $p$, $\Phi(p)$ which I assume we will identify with our source.
2. A piece that depends only on $z$, $A^{-2}(z)$.
3. And the rest of it, which depends on $q = p[k\,A(z)]^{-1}$.

I get the impression that this factorization is significant, but I do not understand the motivation at this stage.

### 2. The  effective action

The next step is to plug $\Phi(p,z)$ above (equation 93) into the bulk scalar action and impose the IR boundary condition. The clalim is that this gives the on-shell action,  equation (94):

$$
S_\text{eff} = 
\frac{1}{2}
\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}
\left[
A^3 \Phi(p,z)\left(
\Phi'(-p,z)-bkA\Phi(-p,z)
\right)
\right]_{z=z_0}
=
\frac{k}{2} \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}
F(q_0, q_1) \, \Phi(p)\, \Phi(-p)
$$

where $F(q_0,q_1)$ are given in equation (95):

$$
F(q_0,q_1) = \mp iq_0 
\left[J_{\nu\pm 1}(iq_0) - Y_{\nu\mp 1}(iq_0) \frac{J_\nu(iq_1)}{Y_\nu (i q_1)} \right]
\left[J_{\nu}(iq_0) - Y_{\nu}(iq_0) \frac{J_\nu(iq_1)}{Y_\nu (i q_1)} \right]
$$

with $\nu_\pm = \alpha \pm 1$.

**Question 3**: I think the point here is that when plugging in the bulk scalar solution into the bulk action, one can integrate by parts so that the bulk piece vanishes by the equations of motion. There are two boundary terms, one on the IR brane that vanishes by the IR broundary condition, and one on the UV brane, which we identify with $S_\text{eff}$. Is that correct?

**Question 4**: I am not sure if I understand the form of $F(q_0, q_1)$.  What are $q_0$ and $q_1$ in this case? I would have thought that $F$ should encode a UV brane-to-UV brane propagator of some sort. Is this simply the $\partial_z - bk A(z)$ operator acting on $\Phi(-p,z)$?

### 3. Self Energy

Finally, we reach the holographic self-energy, $\Sigma(p)$. If I understand correctly, this is the quadratic part of the on-shell action of the strongly coupled dual theory. That is to say: it is the two-point function for the source of the operator $\mathcal O$ that is dual to the 5D field $\Phi$. The lecture notes then say:

$$
\Sigma(p) = \int d^4x \, e^{-ip\cdot x}
\frac{\delta^2S_\text{eff}}{
 \delta\left[A^2(z_0)\Phi(x,z_0)\right]
\,
\delta\left[A^2(z_0)\Phi(0,z_0)\right]
}
$$

**Question 5**: why are we varying the effective action with respect to $A^2 \Phi$ as opposed to just $\Phi$? I think I am often confused by this: why do we sometimes peel off the warp factor?

**Question 5b**: Another place this shows up: in Ponton's [TASI 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3827v1) lectures, the scalar field KK decomposition in a warped space is equation (71):
$$
\Phi(x,y) = \frac{e^{A(y)}}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_n \phi_n(x)f_n(y)
$$
Why have we pulled out the $e^{A(y)}$ here? In the paragraph below the author explains that this gives the $f_n$ a "direct physical interpretation in terms of localization properties of the KK modes" and hence calls the $f_n(y)$ the "physical wavefunctions" when they are normalized this way. It seems to me that the only significance of this is that by peeling off the warp factor, the orthogonaly relation, equation (77), is $\int_0^Ldy\, f_nf_m \propto \delta_{nm}$. That is: the $f_n(y)$ are orthogonal with respect to a flat metric in $y$. Is that the only significance here? It seems like the Ponton lecture is using the same "pull out the warp factor" normalization as the Ghergetta lecture, but I am not totally clear as to why.

[Remark: Price [MSc thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2193) does not do this, see (8.7); and ends up with a self energy expression that looks more reasonable (8.12).]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have sorted this out. I hope it is useful for anyone else who might have been confused by this section of the TASI lectures.

### Normalization of the bulk solution

> **Question 1a**
> I do not quite understand how we fixed $b^{(n)}_\Phi$

The solutions to the bulk equation of motion are linear combinations of $e^{2ky}J_\alpha(e^{ky}m_n/k)$ and $e^{2ky}Y_\alpha(e^{ky}m_n/k)$. There are two unknown coefficients. One is fixed by normalizing the solution.

$b^{(n)}_\Phi$ encodes the other unknown coefficient: the relative coefficient between the two Bessel functions. In fact, there are two unknowns at this stage: first is the value of this relative coefficient, and second is the values of the Kaluza-Klein masses, $m_n$. These are fixed by the boundary conditions.

Earlier in the lectures, the author motivates particular choice of boundary mass term $\sim bk$ so that on has the following boundary condition:
$$(\partial_y - bk)\Phi|_\text{IR, UV} = 0.$$
The choice of the dimensionless parameter $b$ is tuned to a specific value relative the $\Phi$ bulk mass,
$$b=2 \pm \sqrt{4+(M/k)^2} \equiv 2-\alpha.\tag{1}\label{eq:b:def:sec:2}$$ With this choice, the lectures note that there is a zero mode solution. Choosing $b$ amounts to tuning boundary Lagrangian terms. Two remarks:

1. This value of the brane-localized mass parameter $b = 2 \pm \sqrt{4+(M/k)^2}$ is a completely different parameter than $b^{(n)}_\Phi$, the relative coefficient of the bulk solutions. They just happen to both be called $b$.
2. The above boundary conditions and notation are used in Section 2 of the lectures. In Section 4 the author uses a slightly different notation, where $b\to b_\pm \equiv 2\pm \alpha$ and $\alpha$ is now assumed to be the positive root. (Compare this to the Section 2 notation, where $b=2-\alpha$ and $\alpha$ can have either sign implicitly: $\alpha = \pm \sqrt{4+(M/k)^2}$.)

Something helpful happens with that choice of $b$ in $\eqref{eq:b:def:sec:2}$. When we impose the boundary conditions on a generic KK bulk profile $f_n$, the expression simplifies considerably. When you take the derivative $\partial_y f_n(y)$, there are terms that contain, say, $J_{\alpha-1}$ and $Y_{\alpha-1}$, and a term that is exactly $bkf_n(y)$.

So when you impose the boundary condition $(\partial_y - bk)f_n(y_\text{IR,UV})=0$, one ends up with a solution that the relative coefficient is simple to write down: $b^{(n)}_\Phi = -J_{\alpha-1}(e^{ky_\text{IR,UV}} m_n/k)/Y_{\alpha-1}(e^{ky_\text{IR,UV}} m_n/k)$ . This is two equations for $b^{(n)}_\Phi$. Consistency of the two equations determines the quantization of the KK spectrum, $m_n$.

### Definition of warped-down momenta, factors of i

> **Question 1(b)**
> I am not even totally sure what $q_1$ means.

and also:

> **Question 4(a):** What are $q_0$ and $q_1$ in this case?

Though this is not explicitly defined in the text, $q_1$ is the warped down "scalar" four-momentum at the IR brane. In Section 4 of the lectures the author uses the subscript 0 to mean the UV brane and the subscript 1 for the IR brane.

The unusual-looking thing here was that all of a sudden there are Bessel functions with factors of $i$ in the argument. It is indeed the case that $q_i = p/(k A(z_i))$. Why does $q$ show up with a factor of $i$? This is a relic of the metric signature, which is $(-,+,+,+,+)$. In this signature, $p^2 = -m_n^2$. Thus when we write $p = \sqrt{p^2} = \sqrt{-m_n^2} = im_n$.  The factors of $i$ account appear to account for this and allow $q$ to be real. In the mostly-minus metric, there are no factors of $i$.

### Separation of variables

> **Question 2:** why is it significant to factorize $\Phi(p,z)$ into three factors?

The short answer is that it is *not* significant that $\Phi$ was factorized into *three* factors. What *is* significant is that we are simply invokin gthe separation of variables to separate $\Phi(p,z)$ into a piece that depends on $z$ and a piece that does not. The $z$-dependent piece happens to depend on $p$, but $\Phi(p)$ is independent of $z$.

This is analogous to the KK decomposition where the 4D KK mode $\phi^{(n)}$ depends on 4D space (or equivalently 4D momentum), but the bulk profile is both $z$-dependent and depends on the particular KK mode, where the KK mode dependence is through $m_n^2 = - p^2$ (in the mostly-plus metric).

We see the same thing here where the Bessel functions have arguments that depend on $\sqrt{p^2}$, where $p^2$ is the squared four-momentum.

### Connecting the self-energy and bulk solution

> **Question 3:** I think the point here is that when plugging in the bulk scalar solution into the bulk action, one can integrate by parts so that the bulk piece vanishes by the equations of motion. There are two boundary terms, one on the IR brane that vanishes by the IR boundary condition, and one on the UV brane, which we identify with $S_\text{eff}$. Is that correct?

> **Question 4(b):** I am not sure if I understand the form of $F(q_0,q_1)$. Does $F$ should encode a UV brane-to-UV brane propagator of some sort.

Let us be a bit more clear about what's going on. With the convenient choice of the brane-localized mass parameter $b$ in $\eqref{eq:b:def:sec:2}$, we find that
$$
\left(\partial_y - bk)\Phi(p,y)\right|_{\text{UV}}
= ke^{2ky}\left(\mp iq_\text{UV}\right)
\left[
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{UV})
-
\frac{
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
}{
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
}
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{UV})
\right]\phi(p)
$$
where
$$
q(y)=\frac{p}{k}e^{ky} \ .
$$
Compare this to the solution to the bulk equation of motion subject to only the IR boundary condition:
$$
\Phi(p,y)
= e^{2ky}
\left[
J_{\alpha}(iq)
-
\frac{
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
}{
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
}
Y_{\alpha}(iq)
\right]\phi(p)
$$
and we can thus write
\begin{align}
\left(\partial_y - bk)\Phi(p,y)\right|_{\text{UV}}
&= \mp ikq_\text{UV}
\frac{\left[
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{UV})
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
-
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{UV})
\right]
}{
\left[
J_{\alpha}(iq_\text{UV})
Y_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
-
J_{\alpha\pm 1}(iq_\text{IR})
Y_{\alpha}(iq_\text{UV})
\right]
}\Phi(p,y) 
\\
&\equiv
F(q_\text{UV},q_\text{IR})\,
\Phi(p,y)  \tag{2}\label{eq:F}
\ .
\end{align}
Here we recognize the ratio of Bessel functions that is the Wronksian of the solutions to the homogeneous bulk equation of motion---this shows up when solving for the bulk propagator using the method of variations. (This is a good cross check that we're on the right track.) Of course, this is no surprise because we are simply plugging in the solutions to the bulk equation of motion subject to the IR (and only IR) boundary condition.

The relevant terms in the UV brane action come from the integration by parts of the bulk kinetic term (yielding a $\partial_y$) and the brane-localized mass proportional to $bk$. These terms in the action look like:
\begin{align}
S_\text{eff} &= \frac{1}{2}
\int_\text{UV} d^4x \Phi(x,y_\text{UV})
(\partial_y - bk)\Phi(x,y_\text{UV})
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int d^4x \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{d^4\bar{p}}{(2\pi)^4}
e^{-i(p+\bar{p})\cdot x}
\Phi(p,y_\text{UV})
(\partial_y - bk)\Phi(\bar{p},y_\text{UV})
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}
\Phi(p,y_\text{UV})
(\partial_y - bk)\Phi(-p,y_\text{UV}) \ ,
\end{align}
where we used $\int d^4x e^{-iq\cdot x} = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(q)$ to force $\bar{p}=-p$ upon integrating over $d^4p/(2\pi)^4$. Now we can plug in $\eqref{eq:F}$ to find
$$
S_\text{eff} = \frac{1}{2}
\int_\text{UV} \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \Phi(p,y_\text{UV})
F(q_\text{UV},q_\text{IR})
\Phi(-p,y_\text{UV}) \ .
$$
Recognize at this point that because $F$ depends on $p$ through the $q$ variables, the integrand is *not* local in space. To emphasize this point: if $F$ were independent of $p$, then one could use the convolution theorem to Fourier transform back into position space where you will find a convenient $\delta$-function that forces $\Phi(p)$ and $\Phi(-p)$ to be evaluated at the same spacetime position $x$. However, because there is additional $p$ dependence in $F$, this argument fails and the effective action connects $\Phi$ at different 4D spacetime points. This is, of course, exactly what the bulk propagator (which we have "integrated out") does for us.

### Normalization source field

> **Question 5**: why are we varying the effective action with respect to $A^2\Phi$ as opposed to just $\Phi$? I think I am often confused by this: why do we sometimes peel off the warp factor?

In equation (96) of the lectures, the author writes the holographic self-energy:
$$
\Sigma(p) = \int d^4x \, e^{-ip\cdot x} 
\frac{\delta^2 S_\text{eff}}{
\delta(A^2_\text{UV}\Phi(x,y_\text{UV}))
\delta(A^2_\text{UV}\Phi(0,y_\text{UV}))
} \ .
$$
I am sticking to $y$ coordinates, though the author shifts to $z$ coordinates. This changes some intermediate steps since $\sqrt{g}$ is a bit different in the exponential versus the conformal ($z$) coordinates, but it does not affect this particular question.

The direct answer is that this line appears to be a typo. We know from earlier in the lectures that the $N$-point functions of the dual (CFT) operator in the dual theory are variations of the effective UV-brane localized action with respect to the bulk field evaluated on that boundary. This means the variation should be with respect to $\delta\Phi(x,y_\text{UV})$, not $\delta(A^2(y_\text{UV})\Phi(x,y_\text{UV}))$

One point that is skimmed over is the factor that the author calls $g_\phi$. The above paragraph needs one more tweak: because there is already a brane-localized kinetic term, the variation should be with respect to the canonically normalized brane-value of $\Phi$. In particular, the brane kinetic term takes the form
$$
\int_\text{UV}d^4x \, g_\phi^2 (\partial\Phi)^2 \ .
$$
The $g_\phi^2$ factor not only accounts for the size of this term (which is in principle generated by bulk dynamics), but also the fact that the $\Phi$ field has mass-dimension 3/2 rather than the appropriate mass dimension 1 for a 4D scalar field. What we really want to vary with respect to is $\phi_0(x)$, the source field in the CFT that we identify with $\Phi(x,y_\text{UV}$. This identification does not make dimensional sense. The proper identification is $\phi_0 = g_\phi\Phi(y_\text{UV})$, and so we should vary with respect to $\delta g_\phi \Phi(y_\text{UV})$.

**Bonus**: Please note that the author says $A(y_\text{UV}) = 0$. This is not the case, I think there is confusion with a standard notation where the metric is defined as $ds^2 = e^{-2A(y)}{dx^2} - dy^2$. In the present lecture, $A(y)$ has been defined to be $e^{-2ky}$. So in the author's notation, the appropriate limit is $A(y_\text{UV})\to 1$, which corresponds to $A\to 0$ in the "standard notation".

### Meaning of "physical" normalization

> **Question 5b**: Another place this shows up: in Ponton's TASI 2011 lectures, the scalar field KK decomposition in a warped space is equation (71)...

This cross-reference was part of my initial confusion. In those lectures, the author makes a point to define "physical" normalizations or "physical" wave functions. That author's definition of "physical" is that the wavefunctions are orthonormal with respect to the flat space L2 norm. In other words: the author pulls out warp factors so that the wave functions $f_n(y)$ satisfy
$\int dy \, f_n(y)f_m(y) = \delta_{mn}$.